I'm having a problem with an agent's events
I am making a supply chain model in anylogic. It has raw material distributors, which arrive at the factory. Paper is produced in the factory, which is then distributed to two retailers.
The problem occurs in the Factory agent events, since I configured them to run once a day each and they are not complying.
The "FabricarPapel" event should check if it should make paper and update the stock_papel as long as the stock_troncos is greater than zero.
The "PedirTroncos" event should order logs from distributors once a day and update the stock_troncos
What I want is that paper is made once a day as long as the log stock is greater than zero. And I want logs to be ordered from distributors once a day, as long as the log stock is less than 5000 tons, which is the maximum stock capacity.
I am attaching the link to the model and the database. I hope someone can help me :)
Model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A-4jUS2YaY9lud_CLkysS7MxHl6QNUM1/view?usp=sharing
Database: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vS8AeA88Gzq2t61Klv4X_na-LFh6HfZBT7Qr4tSlCUs/edit?usp=sharing

Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. You have a higher chance to get replies by adding screenshots of the specific issue, not the entire model (few of us have the time). In other words: Do not just ask "this does not work! Why?" Help us help you. Here is a really good deep-dive into how to ask good questions here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow . Welcome again, happy to help
